# Store Value From df to Variable

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am trying to extract a value out of a dataframe and put it into a variable. Then later I will record that value into an Excel workbook.

First I run a SQL query and store into a df:

```
df = pd.read_sql(strSQL, conn)
```

I am looping through another list of items and looking them up in the df. They are connected by MMString in the df and MMConcat from the list of items I'm looping through.

```
dftemp = df.loc[df['MMString'] == MMConcat]
Category = dftemp['CategoryName'].item()
```

I get the following error at the last line of code above. ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

In the debug console, when I run that last line of code but not store it to a variable, I get what looks like a string value. For example, 'Pickup Truck'.

How can I simply store the value that I'm looking up in the df to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Index by row *and* column with `loc` to return a series, then extract the first value via `iat`:

```
Category = df.loc[df['MMString'] == MMConcat, 'CategoryName'].iat[0]
```

Alternatively, get the first value from the NumPy array representation:

```
Category = df.loc[df['MMString'] == MMConcat, 'CategoryName'].values[0]
```

The docs aren't helpful, but [`pd.Series.item`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.item.html) just calls [`np.ndarray.item`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html) and only works for a series with one value:

```
pd.Series([1]).item()     # 1
pd.Series([1, 2]).item()  # ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm now getting this error: IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0` This means your condition has not been matched. You haven't specified what you need in this scenario. You can use a `try... except IndexError` construct, or use `next(iter(df.loc[df['MMString'] == MMConcat, 'CategoryName'].values), -1)` where `-1` is your fallback value.